# Can I rename the "New Document" option to something else?

Tags: nautilus, 22.04, context-menu

When putting a template document in the "Templates" folder, the context menu entry reads "New Document". Can I rename it to something else for example "Create".

Comment: I don't think so, without recompiling Nautilus file manager.

Comment: @FedKad should be possible. When you switch language it switches to that language.

Comment: That may be where to look then: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558768/in-which-file-place-does-gnome-store-the-translations-for-other-languages